# How can I dump UI objects programatically in Appium?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, appium-android

I have a C# project with Appium for Android to test Xamarin Android App.

I normally do *Find Elements* and *Press Elements* actions using Appium driver.

Now I am searching for a possibility to dump the entire UI objects and validate whether all the objects are present in the UI.

I am aware of *UiAutomatorViewer.bat*, but it is a manual activity. I want to do it programmatically to some XML format (or whatever possible).

Is there any way to do dump programmatically? Any alternative suggestion is also welcome.

Additional note: I know *squish helps* in that, but it is a paid version.

Comment: Hello, I found [this](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/1868) for you.

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Joe,

For Appium Android in C#, use below command:

```
Driver.PageSource;
```

This will return UI dump as xml.

Comment: Glad it helped, please mark your answer, so it can help others.